# Strange includes when compiling httpuv

Tags: r, g++

I'm trying to compile httpuv (latest version from https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv) using R 3.1.1 and Rcpp 0.11.3. However, the compile fails on the following command

```
    g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o httpuv.so RcppExports.o filedatasource-unix.o filedatasource-win.o 
http.o httpuv.o md5.o set_invalid_parameter.o uvutil.o 
websockets-base.o websockets-hixie76.o websockets-hybi03.o 
websockets-ietf.o websockets.o Successfully loaded .Rprofile at Mon Mar 2 14:21:42 2015 Goodbye at Mon Mar 2 14:21:42 2015 ./libuv/libuv.a ./http-parser/http_parser.o ./sha1/sha1.o ./base64/base64.o
```

For some reason the string "Successfully loaded .Rprofile at Mon Mar 2 14:21:42 2015" is being included in the g++ invocation. I am completely stumped as to where this is coming from.

Does anybody have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a non-standard `~/.Rprofile` or related startup script -- see `help(Startup)` for the full list.

As the compilation and tests invoke R, you don't want this to get in the way.  I do use such script myself, but make sure I protect code by `if (interactice()) { ... }`.

Comment: `interactive` probably :)